# How to install Adobe Reader 11.x onto Mint 18 x64 (Ubuntu 16.04) using Wine 1.8

Tags: wine, winetricks, acrobat-reader

According to this page:
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=27093

I should first invoke these lines:

```
winetricks atmlib 
winetricks riched20 
winetricks wsh57 
winetricks mspatcha
```

My Wine version follows:

```
wine --version

wine-1.8
```

But this or similar I get in every case:

```
winetricks atmlib 

------------------------------------------------------
You are using a 64-bit WINEPREFIX. If you encounter problems, please retest in a clean 32-bit WINEPREFIX before reporting a bug.
------------------------------------------------------
Executing w_do_call atmlib
Executing load_atmlib
Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/6/A/E6A04295-D2A8-40D0-A0C5-241BFECD095E/W2KSP4_EN.EXE to /home/vlastimil/.cache/winetricks/win2ksp4
--2016-11-10 07:56:29--  http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/6/A/E6A04295-D2A8-40D0-A0C5-241BFECD095E/W2KSP4_EN.EXE
Resolving download.microsoft.com (download.microsoft.com)... 23.32.120.68, 2a02:26f0:ef:193::e59, 2a02:26f0:ef:190::e59
Connecting to download.microsoft.com (download.microsoft.com)|23.32.120.68|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2016-11-10 07:56:30 ERROR 404: Not Found.

------------------------------------------------------
Downloading http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/6/A/E6A04295-D2A8-40D0-A0C5-241BFECD095E/W2KSP4_EN.EXE failed
------------------------------------------------------
```

If I get it right, these files are no longer available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your copy of [Winetricks](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks), this issue [has been fixed](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/issues/600).

You may directly download it:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Winetricks/winetricks/mast‌​er/src/winetricks
```